# Excel 2007. Data Tab is grayed out. Nothing on that Tab is available

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I'm trying to sort a file to which I add rows daily.  I usually have no trouble sorting, but from some reason all the items on the Data Tab are 'grayed out' and unavailable. Any idea what's caused this?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you may be selecting something that doesn't allow data sorting. Try selecting the entire spreadsheet (Using the little square where the letters and numbers meet) and attempting it again.

Comment: Thank you.  You were on the right track.  It was something on sheet2 that was causing it.  I've got it sorting again.  Thanks again for the advice.